Getting 404 when I try to hit a route in flutter web docker container
I created a docker container from a Flutter web project with 1 route ('/public'). While running from the IDE, it works as expected. When I hit '/public', it returns the expected page, and for any other route, it redirects me to another website.
I run flutter build web to create a build.
I copied build/web/ to another folder and created the following Dockerfile inside it:
FROM nginx:1.21.1-alpine
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80

When running it with a docker container it doesn't work as expected. It redirects me to another website for any other route and it gives 404 when I hit '/public'.
I am not getting why it is giving 404 for '/public'.

Depending on how you've set up your router, you may need to tell nginx to always serve index.html regardless of the URL if it 404s.  This is covered in the "deploying a flutter web app" in flutter.dev
